# parent class method returns null in its daughter __construct()

Tags: php, oop

I tried a code which I called a parent method in its daughter __construct and itreturns NULL,
I dont know why? I would be very happy if anyone could explain to me why.
Thanks in advance.

***Here is my code***

```
 <?php
 class me
 {
   public $arm;
   public $leg;
   public function __construct()
   {
     $this->arm = 'beautiful';
     $this->leg = 'pretty';
   }

   public function setLeg($l)
   {
     $this->leg = $l;
   }

   public function getLeg()
   {
     return $this->leg;

   }
 }

 class myBio extends me
{

  public $bio;
  public function __construc()
  {
    $this->bio = $this->setLeg();
  }

  public function newLeg()
  {
    var_dump($this->bio);
  }
  public function tryLeg()
  {
    $this->leg = $this->getLeg();
    print $this->leg;
  }
}

$mB = new myBio();
$mB->newLeg();
$mB->tryLeg();
 ?>
```

When I call:
      $mB = new myBio();
      $mB->newLeg();

, it returns
    NULL,

**BUT**

```
$mB->tryLeg();
```

returns e string, 'pretty'.

Comment: `$this->bio = $this->setLeg();` Typo, `set != get`

Comment: @scragar: Should be the answer since it should works with Typo fixed

Comment: @niconoe I posted it as a comment because I didn't even read the question, I was just scrolling through and noticed a setter used without an argument. For all I knew at the time the question was completely unrelated to my comment, and the comment was incidental.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo on this line:

```
$this->bio = $this->setLeg();
```

You're calling your setter, not your getter, and since the setter doesn't return a value you're getting null instead.

You've also misspelled construct:

```
     public function __construc()
```

And you need to call the parent constructor.

```
<?php
class me
{
     public $arm;
     public $leg;
     public function __construct()
     {
          $this->arm = 'beautiful';
          $this->leg = 'pretty';
     }

     public function setLeg($l)
     {
          $this->leg = $l;
     }

     public function getLeg()
     {
          return $this->leg;

     }
}

class myBio extends me
{

    public $bio;
    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->bio = $this->getLeg();
    }

    public function newLeg()
    {
         var_dump($this->bio);
    }
    public function tryLeg()
    {
         $this->leg = $this->getLeg();
         print $this->leg;
    }
}

$mB = new myBio();
$mB->newLeg();
$mB->tryLeg();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but I corrected that typo but its still returning NULL

Comment: @Dr.Professor , check that answer.